# authStateChanges only work if in debug mode

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, release

I have a flutter app and everything was fine until i want to release it.
I'm using firebase for auth.

I'm using: 
firebase_core: ^0.7.0 
firebase_auth: ^0.20.0

In debug mode or in release, my firebase auth login works fine. My problem is after that.
I have a decentralized 'listener' to firebaseAuth.authStateChanges. Here is where i control my app authentication. This is my buildSelf$ function in my auth repository(where i build the auth state listener):

```dart
    ReplayConnectableStream<AuthState> buildSelf$() {
        return Rx.concat([
          Stream.value(AuthInit()),
          firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().switchMap((firebaseUser) {
            print('[AuthRepository][buildSelf][authStateChanges] firebaseUser');
            print(firebaseUser);
            if (firebaseUser == null) {
              return Stream.value(Unauthenticated());
            }
            /* continue function */
            return Authenticated(firebaseUser: firebaseUser);
          })
        ]).publishReplay();
    }
```

buildSelf$ is a method for my AuthRepository. And i initialize it on:

```
  AuthRepository._() {
    Firebase.initializeApp().then((app) {
      _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      state$ = buildSelf$();
      state$.connect();
    });
    setPackageInfo();
  }

  static final AuthRepository instance = AuthRepository._();
```

All this code is inside my AuthRepository.
The problem is:
When i'm running my app in debug mode. Every thing works fine. I can login and my app (my navigator observer uses the auth repository state$) and i'm redirected to home page. [Here a printscreen from terminal in [debug mode. success authStateChanges emit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mf82.png)
But when i'm running im release mode, my login response shows in my terminal 'success' but my listener does not show state changes. Here a printscreen from terminal in [release mode. authStateChanges emit only 1 time(when opening)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIBAR.png)

I'm realy lost about whats going on. I tried even to call this authStateChanges directly in my app.dart but still the same way(in release, only checking auth state once).

**Solution:**

- After 3 days of headache, i finally found out my problem:
  My app does not initialize firebase app on root (main). So i have to initialize it every time i need to use some firebase package.
  I believe that every time one app was initialized, the others failed.

I move my firebase.initializeApp() to my main function and remove every other firebase initialize. Then, everything works fine.
This is my main:

```
void main() async {
    /* ... main code ... */
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(App());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did implement a project with the presented methods in release mode in my iPhone but wasn't able to reproduce the problem, the implementation I did to reproduce the project was:

```dart
class _TestFirebaseState extends State<TestFirebase> {
  bool userLogado = false;

  _loginLogout() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: 'teste1@teste.com', password: '123456');
    } else {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final stream = Rx.concat(
      [
        Stream.value('começou'),
        FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().switchMap<String>(
          (user) {
            debugPrint('user: ' + user.toString());
            if (user == null) {
              return Stream.value('unauth');
            } else {
              return Stream.value('auth');
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    ).publishReplay();

    stream.listen((value) {
      debugPrint('value: ' + value);
      this.setState(() {
        this.userLogado = value == 'auth';
      });
    });

    stream.connect();
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String text = "sair";
    if (!userLogado) {
      text = "entrar";
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: _loginLogout,
            child: Text(text),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the only detail is that the main component that loads everything in the app has a future builder that awaits the firebase to init:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        // Initialize FlutterFire:
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // Check for errors
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'ocorreu um problema inicializando o aplicativo...',
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

          // Once complete, show your application
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // return LoginPage();
            // return VerifySignIn(homePage: Home());
            return TestFirebase();
          }

          // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
}
```

And another detail is that the firebase configuration is implemented following the flutter tutorial for the platform used.

So in order to evaluate if the app configuration is just fine, I would implement that button app inside the same project so you can evaluate it properly.